# Codeigniter: Unable to echo data

Tags: php, codeigniter, json

Ok folks,

I have an odd issue with a function of mine.

```
public function getOutages($Site)
{
    // pull a json data dump of all outages 
    If(!$Site){
        echo '[{}]';
    }else{
        $this->load->database('default', TRUE);
        $this->db->where('Clear', '0');
        $this->db->where('FracID', $Site);
        $query = $this->db->get('vw_Outages');

        echo json_encode($query->result_array());
    }
}
```

This when accesed directly will not echo anything. By enabling the profiler though it functions fine and outputs the data.

```
public function getOutages($Site)
{
$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
    // pull a json data dump of all outages 
    If(!$Site){
        echo '[{}]';
    }else{
        $this->load->database('default', TRUE);
        $this->db->where('Clear', '0');
        $this->db->where('FracID', $Site);
        $query = $this->db->get('vw_Outages');

        echo json_encode($query->result_array());
    }
}
```

Any insight into this would be more then welcome :D .

Answer (score 7):

CodeIgniter has an output buffering system (which also allows it to do things like cache controller output, set headers, and collect view output).  You don't usually `echo` from a controller method. Do this instead:

```
public function mymethod() {
    $anobject = array();
    $output = json_encode($anobject);

    $this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
    $this->output->set_output($output);
}
```

See the [CodeIgniter documentation for the Output class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/output.html).

Comment: I modified the code as such and the issue still remains.  
public function getOutages($Site)
 {
  // pull a json data dump of all outages 
  if(!$Site){
   $output =  '[{}]';
  }else{
   $this->load->database('default', TRUE);
   $this->db->where('Clear', '0');
   $this->db->where('FracID', $Site);
   $query = $this->db->get('vw_Outages');
   
   $output = json_encode($query->result_array());
  }
  
  $this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
  $this->output->set_output($output);
 }

Comment: Have you tried removing the db code and just outputting a string? It's hard to tell what could be wrong just based on the code you posted, but if you can't even echo a string, that will point in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have output buffering or compression enabled-this could cause problems like this. Also check that the variable you're trying to output isn't empty. If this doesn't help, try using a view to display data.

Comment: ok no to both buffering and compression. As to trying through a view that is also a bust. Thanks though. :)