# How to echo data from CodeIgniter with compression enabled?

Tags: php, json, ajax, codeigniter

We can use `$this->load->view(<file_name>, <dynamic_parameters>)` to load a view file in CodeIgniter. There's also a third arguments that accepts boolean. If it is `TRUE`, then the output will be returned by the expression, otherwise (i.e. `FALSE`) it will be directly sent to the browser. The default is however `FALSE`.

Now I want to wrap the content of the view files in a JSON response to make a AJAX website. What I can do is pass the third argument as `TRUE`, then capture the output in a variable, wrap it in JSON and then `echo` it. It works! But there is a problem.

When I set `$config['compress_output']` to `TRUE` in `application/config/config.php`, then the output is Gzipped before sending to browser. And there is a warning not to `echo` out anything if compression is enabled. In that case one will receive a blank page.

So what is the solution? What is the best way to `echo` out the response wrapped in JSON? Also tell me what should I do even when I **don't** want to wrap output in JSON, and simply `echo` it somehow with compression enabled.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8392061/9038475) helps?

Comment: I believe most servers are going to do the compression anyways, and you don't need to do anything, meaning you don't need to use the compress_output option.

Comment: @Geshode Yeah! that helped. Thanks

Comment: Glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

As  [Geshode](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9038475/geshode) mentioned in the comments, the perfect answer to this question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8392061/4846835).